# Flutter: setState not working/re-rendering UI when navigatorKey added to MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-navigation

I have a `MyApp` stateful widget which hosts the `MaterialApp`. I am using FirebaseAuth stream to listen to user sign-in state changes in the `MyApp`'s State widget and call the `setState` method.

I have added conditional logic to show different screens depending upon user sign-in state.

Everything works fine normally, when user logs in, the app renders the appropriate screen and all the logic seems to do well.

But when I add the `GlobalKey<NavigatorState>()` key to the `MaterialApp`, suddenly the app doesn't now re-render to show different screen when user state changes.

**Sample Code:**

```dart
// Dart Packages
import 'dart:async';

// Flutter Packages
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Firebase Packages
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

// Third Party Packages
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

// Models
class GlobalKeys {
  static final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late User? _user;
  late StreamSubscription<User?> _userSubscription;
  late bool _hasShownOnboarding;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _user = _auth.currentUser;
    _userSubscription = _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (_user == user) return;

      _user = user;
      setState(() {});
    });
    _auth.currentUser?.reload();
    _hasShownOnboarding =
        GetStorage().read<bool>('hasShownOnboarding') ?? false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _userSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: GlobalKeys.navigatorKey,
      scaffoldMessengerKey: GlobalKeys.scaffoldMessengerKey,
      home: _user == null
          ? _hasShownOnboarding
              ? const LoginPage()
              : const OnBoardingPage()
          : const CheckUserPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

When I remove `navigatorKey`, then again it start working. I don't understand what's happening, please help